# Line break in PHP mail not working

Tags: php, email

I am sending a contact form details using PHP mail...

```
$message="Contact Details\r\n";
$message.="Name: ".$_POST['name']."\r\n";
$message.="Phone: ".$_POST['phone']."\r\n";
$message.="Message: ".$_POST['message']."\r\n";

$header = "From: " . $from_name . " <" . $from_mail . ">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: " . $replyto . "\r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
@mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header);
```

But the \r\n not working in recieved mail

```
//Output in mail
Contact Details\r\nName: ABCEDE\r\nPhone: 9999999999\r\nMessage: its my messageeee\r\n
```

How can i add line breaks to this..?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Your mail is in HTTP format. Use `."<br />"` instead of `."\r\n"`

Comment: @SanketShah There's no `Content-type: text/html` header, so why would it be in HTML format? And if it were HTML, it would convert line breaks to whitespace, not literal escape sequences.

Comment: Are you sure you're using double quotes around the `\r\n` and not single quotes? Escape sequences are not processed in single quotes.

Comment: This should work as it seems `text/plain` content type is _set_ (by non set). I'm wondering if there is a way to set default content type for `mail` etc. by `php.ini`.

Comment: Was that the problem? You should fix your question so it shows the actual code with the error. Then I can post an answer.

Comment: I am used single quotes in $message

Comment: There are no single quotes in the question. Why did you post different code in the question than your actual application?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$message  = "Contact Details<br />";
$message .= "Name: ".$_POST['name']."<br />";
$message .= "Phone: ".$_POST['phone']."<br />";
$message .= "Message: ".$_POST['message']."<br />";

$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$header  .= "From: " . $from_name . " <" . $from_mail . ">\r\n";
$header  .= "Reply-To: " . $replyto . "\r\n";
$header  .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

@mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header);
```

Comment: If he wanted to send HTML mail, he would be doing so. There's no reason to force it just to solve this problem.

Comment: @Barmar, if he needs newline, he must add <br /> which will only work in case of html content-type.

Comment: If he's sending plain text mail, he can use ordinary newslines, he doens't need to use HTML.